# Adicionar uma <div> para cada tag <li> - HtmlGenericControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Estou lendo um XML de RSS e adicionando cada noticia a uma tag `<li>`

Preciso que cada tag `<li>` fique dentro de uma tag `<div>`, como posso fazer isso através do  HtmlGenericControl?

Desse jeito

```
              <div>
                <li><span>Ações contra dengue prosseguem em Araruama &ndash; <a href="#">Leia mais</a></span></li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <li><span>Laboratório em Campinas identifica 'impressão digital' do vírus da zika &ndash; <a href="#">Leia mais</a></span></li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <li><span>Agentes arrombam casas fechadas em Recife contra o Aedes aegypti &ndash; <a href="#">Leia mais</a></span></li>
            </div>
            <div>
                <li><span>Universidade de Sorocaba coordena três estudos sobre o Aedes aegypti &ndash; <a href="#">Leia mais</a></span></li>
            </div>
```

Segue abaixo o código:

```
    private void AddMenuItem()
{

    XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

    // Load the RSS file from the RSS URL
    rssXmlDoc.Load("http://g1.globo.com/dynamo/luta-contra-a-dengue/rss.xml");

    // Parse the Items in the RSS file
    XmlNodeList rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");

    StringBuilder rssContent = new StringBuilder();

    // Iterate through the items in the RSS file
    foreach (XmlNode rssNode in rssNodes)
    {

        XmlNode rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
        string title = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";

        rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("link");
        string link = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";



        HtmlGenericControl li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        noticias.Controls.Add(li);

        HtmlGenericControl span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        span.InnerText = title;           

        HtmlGenericControl anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        anchor.Attributes.Add("href", link);
        anchor.InnerText = "Leia Mais";

        li.Controls.Add(span);
        li.Controls.Add(anchor);

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solução é mais fácil do que pensava..
Adicionei

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
noticias.Controls.Add(div);
```

Depois no final

```
div.Controls.Add(li);
```